# Characters really allowed in XML

Tags: xml

Due to some parser error when parsing certain (supposedly) XML data, I had a look at the [XML standar](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)d to figure out what is really allowed. My current qualms are with regard to what is allowed to go into the content of a tag `<bla>some content</bla>`, i.e. what `some content` is allowed to contain.

I have in section 2.4:

```
CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)
```

which means "every sequence of characters that does not contain `<`, `&`, or `]]>`. But on which character set does the negation `[^<&]` actually operate? Is it the full Unicode range (afaik #0x0000 up to whatever), or is it rather the `Char` definition from section 2.2:

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

in which case quite a bunch of characters would need to be escaped in the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our friendly wikipedia has a section devoted to this. I think the explanation is in much easier terms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping

### Valid Characters

> Unicode code points in the following ranges are valid in XML 1.0
>   documents:[9]
>
> - U+0009, U+000A, U+000D: these are the only C0 controls accepted in XML
>     1.0;
> - U+0020–U+D7FF, U+E000–U+FFFD: this excludes some (not all) non-characters in the BMP (all surrogates, U+FFFE and U+FFFF are
>     forbidden);
> - U+10000–U+10FFFF: this includes all code points in
>     supplementary planes, including non-characters.
>
> XML 1.1[10] extends the set of allowed characters to include all the
>   above, plus the remaining characters in the range U+0001–U+001F. At
>   the same time, however, it restricts the use of C0 and C1 control
>   characters other than U+0009, U+000A, U+000D, and U+0085 by requiring
>   them to be written in escaped form (for example U+0001 must be written
>   as  or its equivalent). In the case of C1 characters, this
>   restriction is a backwards incompatibility; it was introduced to allow
>   common encoding errors to be detected.
>
> The code point U+0000 is the only character that is not permitted in
>   any XML 1.0 or 1.1 document.

### Escaping

> XML provides escape facilities for including characters which are
>   problematic to include directly. For example:
>
> - The characters "<" and "&" are key syntax markers and may never appear in content outside a CDATA section.[13]
> - Some character encodings support only a subset of Unicode. For example, it is legal to encode an XML document in ASCII, but ASCII
>     lacks code points for Unicode characters such as "é".
> - It might not be possible to type the character on the author's machine.
> - Some characters have glyphs that cannot be visually distinguished from other characters: examples are
>
>   - non-breaking space ( ) " "
>   - compare space ( ) " "
>   - Cyrillic Capital Letter A (А) "А"
>   - compare Latin Capital Letter A (A) "A"
>
> There are five predefined entities:
>
> - < represents "<"
> - > represents ">"
> - & represents "&"
> - ' represents '
> - " represents "
>
> All permitted Unicode characters may be represented with a numeric
>   character reference. Consider the Chinese character "中", whose numeric
>   code in Unicode is hexadecimal 4E2D, or decimal 20,013. A user whose
>   keyboard offers no method for entering this character could still
>   insert it in an XML document encoded either as 中 or 中.
>   Similarly, the string "I <3 Jörg" could be encoded for inclusion in an
>   XML document as "I <3 Jörg".
>
> "�" is not permitted, however, because the null character is one of
>   the control characters excluded from XML, even when using a numeric
>   character reference.[14] An alternative encoding mechanism such as
>   Base64 is needed to represent such characters.

Comment: So in fact the negation (see my question) is with regard to `Char` which incidentally is, as I just learned, worse than I thought to know. It is not just that a `&#5;` needs to be escaped, it is not at all allowed to appear in an XML document. Uff.

Comment: @Harald in the very worst case, you can use a `[CDATA]` section.

Comment: As far as I understand it currently, even a CDATA section may not contain non-characters like what is encoded by `&#x5;`.